# javascript error when performing npm start in react-virtualized

Tags: react-virtualized

I am trying to test react-virtualized.I used `download-zip` files. 
When I run `npm start` in react-virtualized-master, 
it doesn't render anything with below error. 
Can anyone help to fix this bug?

React Error:

```
Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `Application`.
    at invariant (invariant.js:44)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.instantiateReactComponent [as _instantiateReactComponent] (instantiateReactComponent.js:86)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:388)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:262)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:47)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:397)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:262)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:47)
    at mountComponentIntoNode (ReactMount.js:105)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:138)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "react-virtualized-master" is. Are you talking about the master branch of the react-virtualized git repository?

My guess from the error message you copied was that the wrong version of React was installed (< 15.3) so it's unable to resolve `PureComponent`. This should not be the case if you're running the react-virtualized repo though as 16.0 alpha should be used.

Probably need more information to help with this to be honest.